# Grant privileges on selected tables

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

I have a MySQL 5.x database with about 100 tables. I want to grant *only* `SELECT` privileges on certain tables:

```
show tables from my_db like '%some_pattern%'; # select only tables
```

...and `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` on the rest of the tables.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON schemaName.', TABLE_NAME, ' to ''username'';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaName'
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%some_pattern%'
```

and

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON schemaName.', TABLE_NAME, ' to ''username'';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaName'
  AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%some_pattern%'
```

Then run the statements above, copy the resulting sql and run the resulting to grant the permissions

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to grant privileges to many tables with a single query. You need to do a query for each table. You can try using administrative tools such Adminer or phpMyAdmin or similar.